# FusionAuth: Webhook user.email.verified not triggered when confirmation happend via "Set Password" email

Tags: webhooks, fusionauth

I've observed in the admin panel that a user's e-mail state changes from `Email has not been verified.` to `Email has been verified.` in both cases, either if a verification e-mail was confirmed by the user or if the user followed an e-mail link asking him to set his password. But only in the first case a webhook is triggered.
I'm using the default e-mail templates for both cases (named "Email Verification" named "Setup Password") and everything seems to work fine (and a working password is set in the second scenario) except for the missing event in the second case. I've activated all webhooks for the tenant and in the webhook configuration to be sure.
Is that intended? And if so, is there any possibility to get notfied once a user has successfully finished the registration process (by setting a password and confirming his e-mail address on the way)?

Comment: It is intended to implicitly verify the user's email when setting a password via email. If we are not sending an event for email verification during this flow it sounds like a bug. Feel free to open a bug in the FusionAuth issue repo. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for opening the GitHub issue. This will be resolved in the upcoming patch release. https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/418